# Unable to Import Module in Jupyter Notebook: Two Different Directories

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, python-module

New to python, so bear with me.

I have installed Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook successfully, and I have also set up what I think is the correct Path (at least for Anaconda). From an Anaconda prompt, python works as expected, and I can import the modules I need. However, I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import certain modules in Jupyter Notebook (such as cx_Oracle). I think the issue is they are running off of two different directories.

When I run sys.executable in the Anaconda prompt, I get this directory: C:\Users\username\Documents\Anaconda\python.exe

When I run sys.executable in Jupyter Notebook, I get this directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe

Shouldn't these be the same? I would like Jupyter Notebook to execute on the same directory the Anaconda prompt does: C:\Users\username\Documents\Anaconda\python.exe

So my question is: how do I change the Jupyter Notebook directory so it points to the same one Anaconda is using?

Thanks all. This issue has been driving me crazy.

Comment: How do you start Jupyter Notebook? If you start it by typing `jupyter notebook` command in Anaconda prompt, what's the value of `sys.executable`?

Comment: @yiyuezhuo - I was able to start Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda. However, when I go to New -> Python3, I get the following error:

An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb

Comment: You seem to have 2 different Anaconda installations on your machine? Get rid of the one in the Documents folder.